# Android Lollipop Buttons

Tags: android

I'm wondering about the different types of buttons available in android Lollipop. In Google's material design [guidelines for buttons](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html) Google described the three different types of buttons available in API 21. The button, the flat button and the floating action button. I can't seem to find the documentation for the buttons (other than the regular). Does anyone know how to make use of the new button APIs?

Thanks,

26hmkk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no new API for the buttons. Material Design is a concept and can be realised using any API/framework (Android Gingerbread, HTML, Windows::Forms, etc.).

The flat button is a regular button with its elevation set to 0.

The floating action button is a regular button with its shape set to circle.

If you need a FloatingActionButton class or something like that, you should look for third party libraries.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been looking for Google's APIs for a while. This helps quite a bit!